# Register collection: No registration for type MyInterfaceType could be found

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I am investigating SimpleInjector to use it in my project. Below is my code where I get an exception:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        //Case 1:
        container.Collection.Register(typeof(IService<>), new[] { typeof(IService<>).Assembly });

        //Case 2:
        //container.Register<IService<int>, FirstService>();

        var dbService = container.GetInstance<IService<int>>();

        System.Console.WriteLine(dbService.Name);
        System.Console.WriteLine(dbService.Value);
    }
}

public interface IService<T>
{
    string Name { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

public class FirstService : IService<int>
{
    public int Value => 12343;
    public string Name => "First Service";
}
```

I get exception with Case 1. Case 2 works well.

Exception details:

> Unhandled Exception: SimpleInjector.ActivationException: No registration for type IDatabaseConnectionService could be found. There is, however, a registration for IEnumerable<IDatabaseConnectionService>; Did you mean to call GetAllInstances<IDatabaseConnectionService>() or depend on IEnumerable<IDatabaseConnectionService>?

```
    at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowMissingInstanceProducerException(Type serviceType)
    at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceForRootType[TService]()
    at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance[TService]()
    at NetCore.Console.ServiceProvider.Resolve[TService]() in C:\Users\pvha\source\repos\PracticeApp\NetCore.Console\ServiceProvider.cs:line 53
    at NetCore.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\pvha\source\repos\PracticeApp\NetCore.Console\Program.cs:line 8
```

I have some interfaces and each is implemented by one class.

What is the best way to register those interfaces with their implementation?

Comment: Please explain wbat it is you are trying to achieve. The question really is whether you want to use (i.e. inject) a collection of services of always just use one.

Comment: In the latter case, use: `container.Register(typeof(IService<>), new[] { typeof(IService<>).Assembly });`

Comment: @Marco I would like to let SimpleInjector automatically detect the implementation of my interfaces.